# how to get specific value from json file in java

Tags: java, json

I have a json file like this:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "ID" : "1",
            "value" : "value is one"
        }
        {
            "ID" : "2",
            "value" : "value is two"
        }
        {
            "ID" : "3",
            "value" : "value is three"
        }
        {
            "ID" : "4",
            "value" : "value is four"
        }
    ]
}
```

what I want to do is read the josn file and returns the message based on the ID i specify. So for example

```
if (this.list.containsKey("1"))
    {
        return this.list.get(messageTitle);
    }
```

That's what I tried but it returns all the values and ID.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try {
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("jsonFile.json"));
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    // loop array
    JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("list");
    Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How try like this,

```
 JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("list");

 for(int i = 0;i < msg.length();i++ ) {
     JSONObject jsonObj = msg.getJSONObject(i);

     //now get id & value
     int id = jsonObj.getInt("ID");
     String value = jsonObj.getString("value");

     if (1 == id) {
          //now 'value' is what you want
          System.out.println(value);
     }
 }
```

**Note**: can *break* the loop when the result is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `TypeReference` using `ObjectMapper` to convert it into appropriate Map object.

sample code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("jsonFile.json")));

TypeReference<Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>>() {};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    Map<String, ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> data = mapper.readValue(reader, typeRef);
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = data.get("list");
    for (Map<String, String> map : list) {
        if (map.get("ID").equals("1")) {
            System.out.println(map.get("value"));
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("There might be some issue with the JSON string");
}
```

output:

```
value is one
```

Comment: No need to convert to List/Map -- JSONArray and JSONObject implement List/Map functionality.  (And much more cleanly than the native classes, not to mention the ugliness of ObjectMapper.)

Comment: Hi thank you so much actually I need additional jar file (jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.0.jar) when I added this it complained so it seems there is another dependency to this jar file. I was wondering you could help me regarding that. thanks

Comment: It's a standard library. You can use it freely.

Comment: ya I can use it freely but it complains about typeRef. CAn you explain what it is?

Comment: so you are not interested to add any new jar from `jackson` API?

Comment: actually when I use your code there is a red line under  mapper.readValue(reader, typeRef); and it suggested me to configure the build path. and after I searched I realized that I need to add a jar file from Jackson. and after I added it the error still existed so I was thinking maybe there is another dependancy to this jar file

Comment: It's `org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference` which is inside `jackson-core-asl.jar`